{tabularx} | Vertical Alignment in Tables comprising pictures
Again I'm struggling with constructing the simplest of tables.
The scenario:
I'd like to generate a very basic table, where the very first cell shows an image. The adjacent cell's text, though, should be vertically centered.
That's my code so far:
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l | X|}
            \hline
            \framebox(0.2\textwidth,0.2\textwidth){Placeholder} &  B \\ \hline
            C & D \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

As usual: Thanks in advance!

Have a look at the valign option from the adjustbox package.

Thanks for your suggestion. I was wondering, if there wasn't a kind of...implemented solution, though.
Another thread showcased a similar topic. One of the suggested solutions was to place
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
That does work, if both columns are defined as X.

Pictures are, by default, placed with the bottom edge on the baseline.
You could use the adjustbox package or a “hand-made” command, together with the m column type.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for the first picture

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

% for the second picture
\newcommand{\centerincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l | X|}
\hline
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=3cm]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\hline
\centerincludegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


My personal preference would go to
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}{m}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=3cm]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\addlinespace
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=3cm]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Even better:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\addlinespace
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image} & \lipsum[1][1-3] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


